# How to know the order of thread in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am writing a muti thread program(concurrent list with replace method) in JAVA. After I finished it, I find the actually value is different from expected value. How can I know the sequence of the program when having that wrong output. I know the way to debug the muti thread program in the sequence I decide. But, as I can't figure out where is wrong with my program logic. I can't design a sequence to let the wrong output happen. 
So, is there any method I can follow the sequence that the system decides instead of me. Or is there any better way to debug a muti thread program?
(The program is a little complicated, So just look at the code to find the error is not suitable.)

Comment: Clearly your program is running into data race. You must be having a shared variable or reference which is being modified by the threads. Use locks or atomic variables.

Comment: Posting code might also help.

Comment: you can't really ask for help with the amount of information you provided.can you please add info regarding how are you achieving concurrency ? are you using executors or runnables ? and btw, there is no implicit control to the *sequence* of execution of threads in java (multithreaded = non-sequential). although, there are a few techniques which you can use to achieve that. the info you provided is just too less !!!

Comment: Re, "The program is a little complicated" and "is there any better way to debug a muti thread program?" Try to reduce your program to a _[short, self-contained compilable, example](http://sscce.org/)_. If you trim away everything that works, then whatever is left will be the part that's broken. You'll either see for yourself _why_ it's broken, or else you'll have something small enough that you can post the code here, and ask other people to help you understand it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's the first time I ask question here. Sorry for the poor description of the question. I am doing a lazy concurrent list with replace function. I seems to find the wrong code. But still I got a deadlock problem. The solution is to use Jconsole to find waiting threads and use debug in IDE to suspend them. Thanks for teaching me how to ask question here. :)